# Laravel : Many to many insertion

Tags: php, laravel, loops, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two models, `User` and `Team`
The relationship between them is `ManyToMany`:

In `User`:

```
public function teamMembers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Team')->withPivot('id');;
}
```

And in `Team` :

```
public function teamMembers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('id');;
}
```

Now i want to add users to a specific team. So the pivot table name is `team_user`.

Now the data i want to insert to pivot table is :

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "mlwoAgCQYals1N1s2lNa4U5OTgtMNHh9LUhNGrWh"
  "team_id" => "1"
  "members_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "4"
  ]
  "status" => "1"
]
```

What i am doing in my controller :

```
$team_id = $request->get("team_id");
$team = \App\Team::findOrFail($team_id);
foreach ($request->get('members_id') as $key => $value) {
    $team->teamMembers()->attach($team);
    $team->save();
}
```

But it only inserts one record, I mean the `team_id` and the first `member_id`.
I want it to create one record per member from the `members_id` array. How am i gonna do that ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should pass an array of user IDs to the [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method.

> For convenience, `attach` and `detach` also accept arrays of IDs as input

Change your code to:

```
$team = \App\Team::findOrFail($request->team_id);
$team->teamMembers()->attach($request->members_id);
```

Comment: Perfect, i just forgot to pass the array. Thanks dude

Comment: @Alexey, there is the `sync`option too, you could update the answer to have it fullfilled, just a suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: can I add without saving in db? I mean to make dummy objects and attach the related instance without persisting anything in db

Answer (score 0):

```
//
  $user = User::find(1);
  $teams = [1,2,3,4];

  $user->teams()->sync($teams);
```

```
Result pivot team_user tabble: remember  (php artisan make:migration create_team_user_table) anphabet table name order

user_id : 1 1 1 1
team_id : 1 2 3 4
```

```
User Model:

 public function teams(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }

Team Model
public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: Some comment/explanation re. your method would add to /improve your answer