# how to save array data coming from view in laravel

Tags: laravel

**This the data when user submit the form :**

```
POST Data

_token  
"JNDt8WC6kVbvrSdFTKSGnHsfzTuIsbthslf5Gqjs"

invoice_number  
"15"

dateofbill  
"2019-04-19"

customer_name   
"praveen kumar tiwari"

customer_mobile 
"8924001750"

sno 
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]

item_name   
array:3 [▼
  0 => "jeans"
  1 => "shirt"
  2 => "lower"
]

qty 
array:3 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "3"
  2 => "2"
]

price   
array:3 [▼
  0 => "20000"
  1 => "232"
  2 => "12"
]

gst 
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1200"
  1 => "22"
  2 => "12"
]

discount    
array:3 [▼
  0 => "100"
  1 => "23"
  2 => "12"
]

textarea    
""
```

i cannot be able to store this data into a table. i am trying with for loop but getting an error "Undefined offset: 3".

**Code inside the controller**

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($request['sno']);$i++)
        {
            $invoice = new Invoice;
            $invoice->sendbill_id=$bill->id;
            $invoice->sno=$request['sno'][$i];
            $invoice->item_name=$request->item_name[$i];
            $invoice->qty=$request->qty[$i];
            $invoice->price=$request->price[$i];
            $invoice->gst=$request->gst[$i];
            $invoice->discount=$request->discount[$i];
            $invoice->save();
 }
```

**i want to store these 3 values comming in the array form (sno,item_name,qty,price,gst,discount) in 3 diffrent rows**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is indeed your loop: `for($i=0;$i<=count($request['sno']);$i++)`.
To be specific it is this right here `<=`:

```
$i<=count()
  ^^
```

Take a look at your array:

```
[
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]
```

You got a total of `3` objects. `count($request['sno'])` will therefore return 3 since the `count()` function does not start counting at `0`!
However, calling an index (e.g. `$request['sno'][1]`) will **not** return the first object (`0 => "1"`) but the second (`1 => "2"`). I think you see where I am going.

Since the loop will go on until `$i` equals `3` the loop will be completed 4 times. At the last time (where `$i == 3`) you try to get the 4th item out of your array which does not exist so an error message pops up: `Undefined offset: 3`.

To solve this just change this

```
$i<=count()
  ^^
```

to `<`. The loop will only be executed if `$i` is still smaller then `3`. This is the case if `$i == 2`. No error message will pop up.

I do not want to attack or hurt you in any way, but it seems to me that you are relatively new to PHP. Of course, that's not a shame, but I'm wondering if a huge framework like Laravel is right for you. First the basics, then comes the advanced. 
But that's only as a small comment and tip from me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use laravel eloquent to save it. Here is some example that you can check it out. [Laravel : Many to many insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949911/laravel-many-to-many-insertion)