# how to insert the pivot relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

consider i have 2 models that have the pivot relationship many to many between them . now when i want to insert the pivot table how can i achieve it currently i am doing this :

```
DB::table('model1_model2')
            ->insert([
                'something' => $something,
                'something2' => $something2,
            ]);
```

and i kinda feel that its not right and i have do save it with some relation ship or sync !! any idea how to do this ?
EDIT‌: 
Added relationship

```
 public function accommodationRoom()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AccommodationRoom::class)->withPivot('guest_first_name','guest_last_name','guest_cell_phone','guest_nationality_id');
    }
```

Comment: visit: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Just insert records as array of first table foreign key and second table foreign key. That's all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949911/laravel-many-to-many-insertion

Comment: Do you have models set up for both tables and do they have the appropriate `belongsToMany` relationships set up? If so, please may you add the code for one of the relationships.

Comment: @RossWilson yes Ross Every thing is up and ready i just wanna know how to insert into database with relationship

Comment: Ok cool. Can you add the code for one of the relationships to your question?

Comment: added the realtion Mr Wilson

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [**Inserting & Updating Related Models** - Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) documentation:

> When attaching a relationship to a model, you may also pass an array of additional data to be inserted into the intermediate table:

```
$model1->accommodationRoom()->attach($accommodationRoomId, [
    'something'  => $something,
    'something2' => $something2,
]);
```

If you're attaching multiple relations then you would would pass a multidimensional array with the keys are the `id` of the relation and the values are the arrays of additional data:

```
$model1->accommodationRoom()->attach( [
    1 => ['something'  => $something, 'something2' => $something2,],
    3 => ['something'  => 'something else', 'something2' => $something2,],
]);
```

The same is true for the `sync()` method as well.

Comment: @Farshad Did this answer your question or do you still need help?