# How to store $request from form to Pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to store data from a form to a pivot table asset_user.

Model User:

```
public function assets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Asset::class)->withPivot(['amount']);
}
```

Model Asset

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['amount']);
}
```

Migration asset_user:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('asset_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('asset_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('asset_id')->references('id')->on('assets');
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'asset_id']);
        $table->decimal('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My POST form:

```
<div id="form" class="form">
    <form action="{{ route('home.store') }}" method="POST" novalidate>
      @csrf
        <label for="asset_id">Add Asset</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="asset_id" name="asset_id">
        @foreach($assets as $asset)
          <option value="{{$asset->id}}">{{$asset->symbol}} {{$asset->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
          @error('asset_id')
            <div style="color:red;">{{ $message }}</div>
          @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-4">
          <label for="amount">Amount</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" value=''></input>
          @error('amount')
            <div style="color:red;">{{ $message }}</div>
          @enderror
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">speichern</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $validAsset= $this->validate($request,[
        'amount' => 'required|numeric',
        'asset_id' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required'
    ]);
    // dd($validAsset);
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $user->assets()->attach($validAsset, [
        'amount'=> $validAsset['amount'],
        'asset_id'=> $validAsset['asset_id'],
        'user_id' => $validAsset['user_id']
    ]);
```

With my try above i get the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5-3' for key 'PRIMARY

```
insert into `asset_user` (`amount`, `asset_id`, `user_id`) values (7, 3, 5), (7, 3, 5), (7, 3, 5)
```

Why does it try to store all 3 values to all 3 columns? Thanks!

Comment: If there is no default set, you must pass a value for that column in the INSERT

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57075527/14344959

Comment: please checkout https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly and Harsh Patel!
Could you give me a hint please why it inserts all 3 values to all 3 columns, like i have edited above?

Comment: Because you made those 2 columns the primary key `$table->primary(['user_id', 'asset_id']);` and a primary key is always also unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sync method instead of attach
like this:

```
$user->assets()->sync($request->asset_id[], ['amount'=> $request->amount]);
```